# My ajax data submit function throws an error

Tags: ajax

here is my form:

```
<form id="finnform" autocomplete="off">
    <div class="textbaby">
        <label for="name">Dein Name</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="name"  placeholder="Hier eintragen..." class="name-text"><br><br>
        <label for="fname">Text an Finn</label><br>
        <textarea cols="50" rows="10"  placeholder="Schreib hier..." autocomplete="off" name="text"></textarea><br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit-knopf"><br><br>
    </div>
</form>
```

And here my Javascript to send the data to the "data-receive" file:

```
<script>    
    $("#finnform").submit($.ajax({url: 'textannahme.php', type: 'post', data: {name: name, text: text}, success: function(response){
    console.log(response);
    alert("Das Büro von Finn wird sich umgehend um Ihren Text kümmern!")}}));
</script>
```

And the error is: Uncaught ReferenceError: text is not defined.
I dont really know how to fix this. Maybe somebody has an idea?

Thanks

Comment: Set an `id` for your `textarea` element and then get value of it via `const text = document.getElementById('text').value;`.

Comment: @IhorVyspiansky  I think that worked! But now the sql insertion is not working properly : is this code correct? :  $name = $_POST['name'];
$text = $_POST['text'];       mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO personen (name, text) VALUES ('$name','$text')");

Comment: This code is not secure, but in general looks ok. However check which exactly error do you have - `echo mysqli_errno($con)`.

Comment: @IhorVyspiansky The values dont seem to work. I get nothing but spaces in my database...

Comment: First, make sure you send the correct data using JavaScript - check output of `console.log(name)` and `console.log(text)`. If they are not empty, then try `echo $_POST['name'];` `echo $_POST['text'];` on the server side... I don't have your development environment and it's hard to guess what you're wrong with.

Comment: Maybe this will help https://codepen.io/vyspiansky/pen/rNemZMb

Comment: @IhorVyspiansky Your changes worked!! Thank you!!!!!